# How to Cancel invalid Event in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, validation

In HTML5, when you call `checkValidity` method or submit the form, the browser evaluates the fields and if a field is invalid it raises the `invalid` event.

My question is, can I catch this event and cancel it so that the browser thinks this field as valid. I have tried the following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Line2TextBox" runat="server" placeholder="e.g. Street 9" required oninvalid="return Line2TextBox_Invalid(this);" ></asp:TextBox>

function Line2TextBox_Invalid(obj) {
    obj.setCustomValidity('');
    return false;
}
```

When I try to submit the form, it stays invalid.

Comment: `1.` What do you mean by "so that the browser thinks this field as valid"? `2.` How is the validity being checked already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the browser asking for valid input by calling `e.preventDefault();` on the *invalid Event*. This will just stop the browser's UI popup stating the input is required or must match a pattern, and will not enable the submission of the form.

```
foo.addEventListener('invalid', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop it's effects here
    e.stopPropagation(); // stop it from bubbling up
});
```

I made it easier to see the difference on [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4NLQ/) where input *A* will still be `:invalid`, but won't bug you about it in the same way as the normal input *B*.

If any field is `:invalid`, it will prevent submission even if you cancel the *invalid Event*.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, because as soon as the user submits the form the validity is being evaluated. Only then the hooks `onsubmit` and `oninvalid` are called (i.e. at this time the validity you're trying to set has already been evaluated).  Please [read this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/#toc-current-implementation-issues) to see how you can use the `onchange`-event to accomplish what I think you're trying to do.